# SQL stored procedures definition returned after created

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to get a created stored procedure back from Snowflake in the same format, so that each query can be executed, to test and debug?

For example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fred()
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
BEGIN
  select top 100 * from gdp.dimdate
  where monthname(fulldatealternatekey) like  'J%';
  RETURN 'done';
END;
```

is returned as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FRED()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 'BEGIN
  select top 100 * from gdp.dimdate
  where monthname(fulldatealternatekey) like  ''J%'';
  RETURN ''done'';
END';
```

The select statement cannot be executed and now returns an error.

> Syntax error: unexpected 'J'. (line 33)

as it now includes double quotes which are not interpreted correctly.

Comment: If I take your "invlaid" output and run it, it is valid on my snowflake instance. How are you pushing the command to snowflake?

Comment: highlighting the statement and trying to execute it in snowsight 
(this is a dumbed-down version of a real issue when stored procedures contain many lines of code and SQL statements)

Comment: understood. Can you add more example code the represent the complex that make it “become broken”. Because your example is “fine” and behavior explainable.  So we cannot see the gap.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim not sure what you are looking for.
I am trying to work out a way to get the stored procedure definition in a way that allows each statement to be executed for testing and debugging purposes, without introducing possible more errors by manual editing.

Comment: it's your question, if you have "problems" your question does not explain, that doesn't hinder us. Where if you mention, "my SQL if different than I have shown you, and your solution doesn't help me" then cool story, but we cannot help with things we cannot see. You need to close the gap.

Comment: If my stored procedure has a data or other issue in its lifetime and is several 1000 lines long and I am trying to debug/find an error this is an issue.
is there a way I can get the definition from Snowflake so that each step can be executed without modification?

Comment: I myself use the old school, return a msg, here at A, then here at b, etc, and the return the build up SQL to be run, then run it. does it run outside the SP fine, and work my why through like that.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim 
if I highlight individual statements within the definition returned by get_ddl and try and execute each statement it fails. (does the individual statement work for you ?)

  select top 100 * from gdp.dimdate
  where monthname(fulldatealternatekey) like  ''J%'';

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fred()
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
BEGIN
  select top 100 * from gdp.dimdate
  where monthname(fulldatealternatekey) like  'J%';
  RETURN 'done';
END;
```

```
select get_ddl('PROCEDURE', 'fred()');
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "FRED"() RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216) 
LANGUAGE SQL EXECUTE AS OWNER AS '
BEGIN   
  select top 100 * from gdp.dimdate   
    where monthname(fulldatealternatekey) like  ''J%'';   
  RETURN ''done''; 
END';
```

[image]

So it seems it is valid, as I would expect it to be. The two single quotes means put a single quote in the output.

This can be seen/shown via:

select '
BEGIN
select top 100 * from gdp.dimdate
where monthname(fulldatealternatekey) like  ''J%'';

[image]

The SQL parse is seeing the two quotes in a row, and making sense of it correctly.